# lock of openmp seems not to work when dong summation

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am new to openMP and mutli-threading. I need to do some summation work and I know that when writing to the shared variable, it need to use lock like `omp_lock_t`. But when I do so, the result still goes wrong.

The code is:

```
#include <omp.h>

#include <cstdio>
struct simu
{
public:
    simu() : data{ nullptr }
    {
        omp_init_lock(&lock);
    }
    ~simu()
    {
        omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
    }
    void calcluate()
    {
        omp_set_lock(&lock);
        (*data) += 1;
        omp_unset_lock(&lock);
    }
public:
    omp_lock_t lock;
    int *data;
};

int main()
{
    printf("thread_num = %d\n", omp_get_num_procs());

    const int size = 2000;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    simu s[size];
    simu *ps[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        s[i].data = (0 == i % 2) ? &a : &b;
        ps[i]     = &s[i];
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
    {
        ps[k]->calcluate();
    }

    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);

    a = 1;
    b = 2;

    #pragma omp parallel for default(shared) num_threads(4)
    for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
    {
        ps[k]->calcluate();
    }

    printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result is

```
thread_num = 8
a = 1001, b = 1002
a = 676, b = 679
```

I run this code on Win10. Can anyone explain why the result is wrong?

Comment: what is the "correct" output?

Comment: each instance of simu seems to have its own lock. So locks are worthless and you have race condition accessing a and b.

Comment: point of style: don't use old-style arrays. Especially `simu *ps[size]` looks unnecessary. Please use `std::vector` for everything array-like. You have generally too many stars in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lock protects the actual data item from simultaneous writes. Your lock is in the object that points at the item, so this is pointless. You need to let you `data` point to an object that contains a lock.

Comment: I see. So I need a lock for `a` and `b` respectively. But now I just lock `data` which does not change. Thank you!

Comment: That's precisely it.